# GCP Cloud Functions: Node.JS Versions Roadmap

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

Currently GCP Cloud functions only support Node 8. Node8 is out of support since end of 2019. Node10 runtime of GCP functions is in beta phase since April 2019.

Google does not commit to any SLAs on a beta runtime.

As other GCP services and libs require at least Node10, there is basically no way to use GCP functions together with other GCP services in a production setup.

Is there any communication from GCP how and when to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like GCP is now officially supporting Node10. The documentation https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-10-runtime. Node 8 will be deprecated on 2020-06-05.

I'm very unhappy about the bad communication of these changes from GCP. I've heard about the Node10 GA via Firebase newsletter and the very short upgrade window.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine and I investigated this, we work in GCP Support, and there is no communication about this nowadays. If you want, you can create a Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/) to ask for this information.

Comment: I tried to create a Feature Request, but it seems like I don't have sufficient permissions.

Comment: You need a Gmail account. Can you try using this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=1163154)?

Comment: Comment of the GCP Support via their bug tracking system:


_You are right, Node.js 10 runtime is still in beta stage, as documented on the ⁠The Node.js 10 Runtime page. There is no clear-cut date for a general availability version of this runtime, as development work is not entirely predictable, and may encounter unexpected delays due to testing and other activities. Generally speaking, beta stages are not to be viewed as overlong. I hope GA is going to be released soon._

Comment: I see. Well, then it is necessary to wait. I hope it goes fast.